# C, Structure writes only 4 characters

Tags: c

im stuck in writing my code with a problem I cant just deal with. I have to write data from a txt file to structures. The code looks like this:

```
typedef struct uzytkownik_
{
    char *imie;
    char *nazwisko;
    char *oprogramowanie;
    char *ip;
    struct uzytkownik *next;
}uzytkownik;
```

Later in the code i have this:

```
    fgets(tekst,sizeof(tekst),plik);
    sscanf(tekst,"%s",&gl->wsk_u->imie);
    fgets(tekst,sizeof(tekst),plik);
    sscanf(tekst,"%s",&gl->wsk_u->nazwisko);
    fgets(tekst,sizeof(tekst),plik);
    sscanf(tekst,"%s",&gl->wsk_u->oprogramowanie);
    fgets(tekst,sizeof(tekst),plik);
    sscanf(tekst,"%s",&gl->wsk_u->ip);
    printf("%s\n",&gl->wsk_u->nazwisko);
    printf("%s\n",&gl->wsk_u->imie);
    printf("%s\n",&gl->wsk_u->oprogramowanie);
    printf("%s\n",&gl->wsk_u->ip);
```

I know I could use `fscanf` so it would be shorter, and it was so written but I thought that this was the source of my problem so I replaced it with fgets and sscanf. Works the same. The printf's are there to see what is the result. `gl` is the 'head' pointer to my list, `wsk_u` is another pointer to my `uzytkownik` structure. Now whats the problem? So for the given data:

```
Adam
Kowalski
Windows7
174.14.0.1
```

the result is:

```
KowaWind174.14.0.1
AdamKowaWind174.14.0.1
Wind174.14.0.1
174.14.0.1
```

So what it basicly does, it takes 4 characters from a text line and cuts the rest, and then it adds next lines from the text file (also cut to 4 characters beside the last word as you can see). It should look like this:

```
Kowalski
Adam
Windows7
174.14.0.1
```

Why does it work like this and where could be the source of my problem?
EDIT:
Code with memory allocations:

```
    gl->wsk_u=malloc(sizeof(uzytkownik));
    gl->wsk_u->next=NULL;
```

These two lines are just above the `sscanf` code.

Comment: Did you allocate memory for each structure member?

Comment: If that last malloc line is the only malloc in the program, then no wonder. Otherwise... the problem is not possible to reproduce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see some problems here:

1. Not allocated memory for strings
2. Wrong usage of `sscanf`
3. Wrong usage of `printf`

---

You have to allocate memory for string before you use it

```
gl->wsk_u->imie = malloc(size_of_your_expected_string);
//DO this for each member you use with sscanf functon
```

---

Wrong usage of sscanf is the root problem.

```
sscanf(tekst,"%s", &gl->wsk_u->imie);
```

should be

```
gl->wsk_u->imie = malloc(100); //FOr example 100 bytes.
//DO this malloc for all entries
sscanf(tekst,"%s", gl->wsk_u->imie);
```

---

Printing is wrong

```
printf("%s\n",&gl->wsk_u->imie);
```

should be

```
printf("%s\n", gl->wsk_u->imie);
```

Comment: memory is allocated before in the code. When I delete the '&' in sscanf the program stops working.

Comment: I know that the problem is with writing data to my structure. I have 4 strings and one pointer. And writing data in these strings doesnt seem to be working at all. As I wrote up, the problem is, it cuts the text to 4 characters and writes previous 'sscanf''ed lines.

Comment: If you pass variable location, then you are passing wrong. You have to pass to sscanf value of variable. You have to assign memory where it points to first.I've updated my answer.

Comment: @PhoeniX Now you are passing address of variables where they are stored. Since pointer is in your case 4 bytes long address, you can see only 4 bytes. And since you have all pointers in sequence memory, you see only 4 bytes from first 3 pointers and all from last one. Remove that `&` in `sscanf` and `printf`functions. Use `malloc` to reserve memory where sscanf will save data!

Comment: Now its working. Thank you for your help, you saved me a lot of time.